# Iteratively printing out of tables inside r chunk in r markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

i want to print out tables for a PDF document in R markdown.

My code looks like this: ("Table" is the list containing the tables to print out)

```
´´´{r, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE}
for ( j in 1:n){
  print(Table[[j]])
  cat('.   \n')  // i also can't manage do get empty rows between the tables
  print(Table[[2+n+1+j]])
´´´
```

But this only gives out the content of the table as text, it does not consider the table structure.

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get data in proper table structure in pdf you may use `knitr::kable` or any other package which helps in pretty display of dataframes.

````
```{r}
for ( j in 1:n){
  print(knitr::kable(Table[[j]]))
  cat('\n\n\n')
  print(Table[[2+n+1+j]])
}
```
````

Comment: ah ok did not know about that accept thing. do you by any chance also know how to inlude a new page in that context? sth like ´for (...){ print(knitrr:: ......) (...)  \newpage }?

Comment: You can use `cat("\n\newpage\n")` inside the `for` loop.